# Include single and double quotes into `document.querySelector`

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom-events

If I have an array of attributes like this:

```js
let elementsArray = [
  '[name="country_code"]',
  '[name="user_tel_code"]',
  '[name="countryCode"]'
];
```

And I want to loop through them with `loopFunc` function like this:

```js
function loopFunc(elementsArray) {
  for (target of elementsArray) {
    let targetElem = document.querySelector(target);
    console.log(targetElem);
  }
}
```

The output should be each DOM of these targets but instead, it says **null**.

My problem here is that I want to include single and double quotes inside `document.querySelector` at the same time.

Comment: What is `targets`? Should probably be `for (target of elementsArray)`

Comment: @NickParsons my bad, `targets` is `elementsArray`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works just fine. I believe that loopFunc is called at the point in which elements are not yet rendered. Try calling the function when DOM is ready.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  loopFunc(elementsArray)
});
```

Just in case. Here is the element, I created for testing

```
<input type="text" name="country_code">
```